# Uncaught Soap Error

Tags: php, zend-framework, soap, zend-soap

I am making a soap call from inside a try...catch block,

```
        $request->l_Request->Year = $year;      
//      $request->l_Request->Period = $period;      
        try {
            /**
             * 
             * perform getMake request
             * @var stdClass
             */
            $response = $client->getSeries($request);    
            $series = $response->getSeriesResult->Lookup_Struc;                                                                                
            return $series;                      
        } catch (SoapFault $exception) {                        
            /**
             * log exception on soap request
             */
            $this->getLogger()->log($exception->getMessage(), Zend_Log::ERR);
            $this->getLogger()->log($exception->getTraceAsString(), Zend_Log::INFO);
            return false;           
        }  catch (Exception $exception) {                           
            /**
             * log exception on soap request
             */
            $this->getLogger()->log($exception->getMessage(), Zend_Log::ERR);
            $this->getLogger()->log($exception->getTraceAsString(), Zend_Log::INFO);
            return false;           
        }
```

Here's how my output/error looks like

> ( ! ) Fatal error: SOAP-ERROR: Encoding: object has no 'Period'
>   property in C:\wamp\www\FHH\library\Zend\Soap\Client.php on line 1121

But I am unable to catch soap-error using try catch, Is there special way to handle this.

Comment: That is not an [exception](http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php), it's an [error](http://php.net/manual/en/book.errorfunc.php), there is a difference. If you want to catch it, you will have to [convert it to an exception](http://www.google.com/search?q=php+convert+exception+to+error). Although being that it is an `E_FATAL`, you probably won't be able to do this for that specific situation. The PHP native SOAP extension is notoriously difficult to deal with in this respect (amongst others), which is why many applications use [NuSOAP](http://sourceforge.net/projects/nusoap/) instead.

Comment: Make sure `Period` is the right case. It could be a case-sensitive problem.

Comment: DaveRandom thanks, Liyali you're not getting the point I am trying to get an exception/soap-error thats why I commented the code, Point of my question is not why I am getting how should I handle the error, read the question please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use the following class in my applications to turn errors into exceptions:

```
class ErrorHandler
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        set_error_handler( array( __CLASS__, 'handleError' ));
    }

    static public function handleError( $errno, $errstr, $errfile,
                                        $errline, array $errcontext )
    {
        throw new ErrorException( $errstr, 0, $errno, $errfile, $errline );
    }
}
```

You just need to create an instance of it:

```
$errorHandler = new ErrorHandler();
```

An alternative if you're using ZF1 MVC is to rename the constructor to `__initErrorHandler()` and add those two methods to your bootstrap class.

I have successfully used this approach in code that uses `Zend_Soap_Server`, so hopefully it will work for you too.